# Enviar quantidade indeterminada de strings JSON via socket

Tags: c, json, socket

tenho uma aplicação `cliente/servidor` onde o cliente faz uma requisição ao servidor e este faz uma consulta a um `banco de dados` e depois devolve esses dados para o cliente no formato `JSON`, como eu nao sei quantos registros tenho na minha tabela pensei em enviar cada registro em um `send()`, porém no cliente estou perdendo os dados do primeiro `send()`, e o `buffer` do primeiro `recv()` está armazenando os dados dos `send()` sequentes

`Código do servidor:`

```
while((row = mysql_fetch_row(res))){
    sprintf(jobj_string, "{ \"nomeUsuario\" : \"%s\", \"idUsuario\" : \"%s\" }", row[1], row[0]);
    if((send(socketNovo, jobj_string, strlen(jobj_string), 0)) == SOCKET_ERROR){
        perror("Falha ao enviar usuario");
        exit(0);
    }
}
```

`Código do cliente:`

```
for(;;){
    if((recv(socketServidor, jobj_string, 300, 0)) == SOCKET_ERROR){
        perror("socket recv");
        exit(0);
    }
    jobj = json_tokener_parse(jobj_string);
    if(jobj != NULL)
        json_object_object_foreach(jobj, key, val){
            /* processa o JSON */
        }
}
```

o que o servidor manda:

```
{ "nomeUsuario" : "user1", "idUsuario" : "1" }
{ "nomeUsuario" : "user2", "idUsuario" : "2" }
{ "nomeUsuario" : "user3", "idUsuario" : "3" }
{ "nomeUsuario" : "user4", "idUsuario" : "4" }
```

sendo cada linha um send();

o que o buffer do primeiro recv do cliente armazena:

```
: "user2", "idUsuario" : "2" }
{ "nomeUsuario" : "user3", "idUsuario" : "3" }
{ "nomeUsuario" : "user4", "idUsuario" : "4" }
```

ou seja perdi os dados do primeiro `send()`, e matade do segundo, usei o `wireshark` e verifiquei que o servidor está enviando os dados corretamente, outra ideia seria enviar todos os registros em somente um `send()`, mas como eu não tenho como determinar  quantidade  registros existem no meu banco, corro o risco de estourar o tamanho do `buffer` do cliente.

Como seria a melhor forma de enviar os registros para o cliente sem saber o tamanho?